# Connect to Third Party Pusher Channel Server Side

Tags: c#, websocket, pusher

I have seen many examples of connecting to Pusher services server side when you are the owner of the service channel, or at least have the Keys. But does anyone know how to do it for a third party's channel?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about publishing using the HTTP API? If so then you can only do this on public channels. For private and presence channels you need the app secret.